# How do I get my html template to correctly reference uploaded media content?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to reference uploaded memes on my Django web app (development mode). 
I want "account" to reference "media/memes/images/{insert img}" 
**but it's referencing "/account/media/memes/images/{insert img}"**.

Below is account function in views.py:

```
def account(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        user_posts = Meme.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('-published')
    else:
        return _logout(request, timed_out=True)

    files = [m.file for m in list(user_posts)]
    #print("filenames to memes posted by user: ", files)
    return render(request, "account.html", context={"filenames": files})
```

Below is account.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}


<div class="row">
    {% for filename in filenames %}
        <br>
        <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
          <div class="card-content">
            <img src="media/{{ filename }}" width="80%" height="80%"></img>
          </div>
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Below is the output:

```
[07/May/2019 21:26:40] "GET /account/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1563
    Not Found: /account/media/memes/images/michaeljordan.jpg
    [07/May/2019 21:26:40] "GET /account/media/memes/images/michaeljordan.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3418
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to django. Fix: `src="media/` => `src="/media/`

Omitted leading slash [means](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls) "starting from current url". Leading slash means "from the root".

Although this change fixes your issue, this is not the Django way. I suggest you to configure [MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#media-url) and refer these images like:

```
src="{{ m.file.url }}"`
```

in your case `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`